# How to combine several scopes with the google api ruby client?

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-api-ruby-client

I'm using the [google api ruby client](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client)! and want to combine several scopes, eg https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email and https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me?

So far it seems like I can only use either or eg by using 
    client.authorization.scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need to do is pass an `Array` of scopes.

Comment: Thanks! I used '@client.authorization.scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email']' and it worked.